# How to set the Checkbox background

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to set the background color of a `Checkbox`, like this image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _value = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          // height: 16,  // <- I don't want to hardcode the size 16 here
          // width: 16,
          child: ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Checkbox(
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the result I get (without hardcoding the height and width of the `SizedBox`) is this:

[image]

There is a padding around the `Checkbox` that I don't manage to remove. I tried to play with the parameters of `Checkbox` (like `fillColor`, `materialTapTargetSize`, `visualDensity` but there is always a padding.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible in the current `stable` release (`3.7.12`). There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123386) for that.

A [fix](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/125643) got merged so it should be available on the `master` channel or on stable `3.x` with `x > 7` once released:

[image]

```dart
Checkbox(
  fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
     if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return Colors.orange;
     }
     return Colors.green;
  }),
  value: false, // or true to show Colors.orange
  onChanged: (bool? value) { },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Checkbox, you can use an Icon. For example, Icons.check_box_outline_blank or a combination of CupertinoIcons.square and CupertinoIcons.square_fill.

If you want to add a ripple effect to your icon, I use this approach:

```
Widget wrapIcon(IconButton button) {
  return Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: button,
        );
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is ideal. It would force me to re-code the `Checkbox` widget which is actually complex. It follows the theme, has semantics, has ripple effect, a mouse cursor, is animated etc

Comment: Icon is also clickable, so it works with mouse cursor, etc. And if you are concerned about a theme, why change the standard Checkbox? It's your choice, of course.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this code to achieve colored checkbox -

```
  Container(
                          height: 2.5.h,
                          width: 2.5.h,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Checkbox(
                            fillColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                            // fillColor:
                            //     MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            //   (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                            //     if (states
                            //         .contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                            //       return Colors.green;
                            //     } else {
                            //       return Colors.green;
                            //     }
                            //   },
                            // ),
                            value: _isSelected1,
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _isSelected1 = newValue;
                              });
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
```